# Why changing environment's locale does not work?

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, widget, widgetkit

I am trying to localise the Widget.
Setting `.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ja"))` does not work for most of the code:

It only works for:

- `Text(entry.date, style: .date)`

but **does NOT work for:**

- `Text(Date.now.advanced(by: 60*60*12), style: .relative)`
  and
- `if {} else {}` statement

It should display something like:

```
こんにちは世界!
2022年12月31日
11時間, 57分
```

Instead it is displaying this:

[image]

```
struct SuperWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        WidgetView()
            .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ja"))
    }
    
    var languageCode: String? { Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.language.languageCode?.identifier }
    var localeCode: String? { Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier }
    var isJapaneseLanguage: Bool { languageCode == "ja" }
    var isJapaneseLocale: Bool { localeCode == "ja_JP" }
        
    @ViewBuilder
    func WidgetView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            if isJapaneseLocale || isJapaneseLanguage {
                Text("こんにちは世界！")
            } else {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            VStack {
                Text(entry.date, style: .date)
                Text(Date.now.advanced(by: 60*60*12), style: .relative)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems, that styles `relative` and `offset` won't be localised properly using a `Text` view, no matter which locale. I consider this a bug (tested on Simulator iOS 16.2). You may file a bug with a minimal example: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Why doing it manually? If you add support for different languages to the app, and use localizable strings, and so on, everything should work out of the box, no?

Comment: Does it change if you change the localization of the device? Widgets are not like main app views they don’t redraw and injecting to the environment would require a redraw.

Comment: @loremipsum When I try to change the localization of the simulator, it stops responding unfortunately.

Comment: @lazarevzubov I need to take screenshots on different devices (different simulators).

Comment: The only way would be to properly adopt localization and change the device. Widgets don't listen or redraw they are like a GIF and each entry is like one of the images that make a GIF, what is there at `getTimeline` is what the widget will display.

Comment: @user14119170 I would advice against writing code for testing (or screenshot gathering, or whatever,) that affects production. You can always gather screenshots using UI testing tools (XCTest, Fastlane,) by running the app or a simulator with any language you need (using test schemes, test plans, or command line tools.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

I ran your code and assuming that `Locale.autoupdatingCurrent` gets a new locale from `.environment(\.locale, entry.locale)` is the issue.

`@Environment(\.locale) var locale` is the only way you can get SwiftUI's locale.

```
struct WidgetSample_WEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    //This reads SwiftUI's locale not autoupdating
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    
    var languageCode: String? { locale.language.languageCode?.identifier
    }
    var localeCode: String? { locale.identifier }
    var isJapaneseLanguage: Bool { languageCode == "ja" }
    var isJapaneseLocale: Bool { localeCode == "ja_JP" }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(Date.now.advanced(by: 60*60*12), style: .relative) //This does not localize, it is an Apple bug in a Main App as well.
            if isJapaneseLocale || isJapaneseLanguage {
                Text("こんにちは世界！")
            } else {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            
        }
        //This will tell SwiftUI to use `locale`
        .environment(\.locale, .getCustomLocale(entry.languageCode))
    }
}

extension Locale{
    ///Gets locale of provided `languageCode` if `languageCode` == nil the `.current` locale will be returned
    static func getCustomLocale(_ languageCode: String?) -> Locale{
        guard let languageCode = languageCode else {
            return .current //Use device locale
        }
        let locale = Locale(identifier: languageCode)
        return locale //Use language code locale
    }
}
```

**Long Answer**

Since `style: .relative` doesn't work you have to manually implement the updates by providing the necessary entries in the `getTimeline` method and use a custom formatter than uses the custom locale

```
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline
        let currentDate = Date()
        for offset in 0..<60 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: offset, to: currentDate)!
            //All the important data must come from here.
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate.advanced(by: 60*60*12), configuration: configuration, languageCode: "ja")
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

Then your `SimpleEntry` and `View` can look something like this.

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    /// nil uses device's localization
    let languageCode: String?

    // Workaround for Apple bug
    // Needs entries for every minute/second as desired and as allowed by the "Widget Budget"
    var localizedDate: String{
        let f = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        f.locale = .getCustomLocale(languageCode)
        f.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return f.string(for: date) ?? "unable to localize"
    }
}

struct WidgetSample_WEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(entry.date, style: .relative) //This does not localize, it is an Apple bug in a Main App as well.
            
            Text(entry.localizedDate) //Needs entries for every minute/second as desired and as allowed by the "Widget Budget"
            if locale == Locale(identifier: "ja_JP"){
                Text("こんにちは世界！")
            }else{
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            
        }
        //This will tell SwiftUI to use `locale`
        .environment(\.locale, .getCustomLocale(entry.languageCode))
    }
}
```

**Long Answer Part 2**

`String`s can also be localized by SwiftUI if you implement "Localization" in your app/extension. This would remove the `if else` logic where you check the `locale` for `Text("Hello, world!")`.

Here are some basic steps to implement `Localization`

1. Go to PROJECT > Localizations > + > Select languages
2. Create a "Localizable.strings" file
3. Click on the "Localizable.strings" file and in the "File Inspector", "Localize" the file.
4. Click on the "Localizable.strings" file and in the "File Inspector" look at "Localization" and click on the relevant languages.
5. Click on the "Localizable.strings" file and in the "File Inspector" look at "Target Membership" and make sure the widget extension is selected.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-support-for-languages-and-regions

[image]

The English file will look something like

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings (English)
  
*/
"Hello, world!" = "Hello, world!";
```

and the Japanese file will look something like

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings (Japanese)
  
*/
"Hello, world!" = "こんにちは世界!";
```

Then your View can be simplified to look something like this and you would get the English and Japanese versions of the key.

```
struct WidgetSample_WEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    var body: some View {
        VStack{                
            Text(entry.localizedDate) //Needs entries for every minute/second as desired and as allowed by the "Widget Budget"
            
            Text("Hello, world!") //Text knows to look for the "Localizable.strings" file
        }
        //This will tell SwiftUI to use `locale`
        .environment(\.locale, .getCustomLocale(entry.languageCode))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a workaround for the issue in my comment. It's kinda elaborate, but it seems to work.

It also is apparent that the `Text` view does not use a `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` internally.

Note, that the original `Text` facilitates "life updates", which requires a Model to implement this behaviour in the custom view. It uses a timer and a RelativeDateTimeFormatter to accomplish this.

**Update**
In order to make it clear, this code only demonstrates the issue with the broken localisation of the SwiftUI `Text` view when using a `Date` as parameter and `relative` as `style`. It can not be just copy&pasted into your Widget.

Below you can experiment with the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct RelativeDateText: View {
    private let date: Date
    private let unitsStyle: RelativeDateTimeFormatter.UnitsStyle

    init(
        from date: Date,
        unitsStyle: RelativeDateTimeFormatter.UnitsStyle
    ) {
        self.date = date
        self.unitsStyle = unitsStyle
    }

    var body: some View {
        EnvironmentReader(\.locale) { locale in
            _RelativeDateText(
                from: date,
                unitsStyle: unitsStyle,
                locale: locale
            )
        }
    }

    struct EnvironmentReader<Content: View, Env>: View {
        @Environment private var env: Env

        let content: (Env) -> Content

        init(
            _ keyPath: KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Env>,
            content: @escaping (Env) -> Content
        ) {
            self._env = .init(keyPath)
            self.content = content
        }

        var body: some View {
            content(env)
        }
    }

    struct _RelativeDateText: View {
        @StateObject private var model: Model

        init(
            from date: Date,
            unitsStyle: RelativeDateTimeFormatter.UnitsStyle = .full,
            locale: Locale
        ) {
            self._model = .init(
                wrappedValue: .init(
                    date: date,
                    unitsStyle: unitsStyle,
                    locale: locale
                )
            )
        }

        var body: some View {
            Text(model.relativeDateString)
        }

        final class Model: ObservableObject {
            @Published var relativeDateString: String = ""

            private let relativeDateTimeFormatter: RelativeDateTimeFormatter
            private var cancellable: AnyCancellable!

            init(
                date: Date,
                unitsStyle: RelativeDateTimeFormatter.UnitsStyle = .full,
                locale: Locale
            ) {
                let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
                formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
                formatter.locale = locale
                self.relativeDateTimeFormatter = formatter

                cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
                .autoconnect()
                .prepend(Date.now)
                .map { _ in
                    formatter.localizedString(for: date, relativeTo: Date.now)
                }
                .assign(to: \.relativeDateString, on: self)
            }
        }
    }

}

struct RelativeDateText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // Compare the original `Text` with custom `RelativeDateText`:
        VStack {
            Text(Date.now, style: .relative)
            RelativeDateText(
                from: .now,
                unitsStyle: .short
            )
        }
        .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")) // <== "ja_JP" !!
    }
}
```

Comment: `Timer` doesn't work on a Widget

Comment: @loremipsum Too bad, is there an alternative? At least, the example above demonstrates the localisation issue.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thank you for your answer, it provides some insight into why the `Text` with `.relative does what it does when changing `.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ja_JP"))`. However why does `if {} else {}` not work, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Provide the data on `getTimeline` or properly implement localization and change the device's region. I say this so many times on SO, Widgets are like a GIF, and entries are like the images that make a GIF. If the information isn't at `getTimeline`/when the image is captured the widget will not know about it. SwiftUI wrappers spoil us by automating so much, they are useless when it comes to widgets.

Comment: @user14119170 I'm not sure what you mean with "it does not work". You should be more specific. But note, the expressions in if/else evaluate values from static functions which have nothing to do what locale you read from the environment. Furthermore, what I am showing is not related to widgets, it shows the localisation issue when using `Text` with style `relative` or `offset`.

Comment: On a side note you should look into `TimelineView` it is a much better option than a `Timer` (doesn't work in widgets either) it would eliminate so much of your code.

Comment: @loremipsum I should probably have provided a working example as a `Widget` and not as a `View`. But this wasn't the issue - the broken localisation of `Text` is the issue. It sholdn't be terrible difficult to make a widget, though. The timer needs to be removed and the date should be delivered by the TimeLineProvider resp. TimeLineEntry. The idea to use a TimeLineView to demonstrate the localistion issue is of course the better one.  :)

Comment: The issue is that they are trying to inject `locale` not use the device's. `.environment` would have to cause a redraw for the `Bool` to change. Your code is fine for a main app it just doesn't work for a widget which is what the OP is asking about, expecting injection to work in a widget is not IAW how widgets work, they don't redraw.

Comment: @loremipsum I agree, that injecting the locale migt make no sense in a Widget extension, but:  whatever the locale is actually, and whereever it comes from, the SwiftUI `Text` view does not properly localise a `Date` value as a formatted string when `style` parameter equals `relative`. So, `Text(Date.now.advanced(by: 60*60*12), style: .relative)` will never render correctly for any locale (except en). Just let the code run, and you will see.

Comment: The Image shows that, I don't have to run the code. That can be worked around with a computed property and `TimelineView`. But, not in a Widget, what `.relative` and `.timer` styles can do it a widget can't be duplicated, the closest is for an entry for every second but that isn't guaranteed to work.